# Nestjs microservices with custom transport, what about controllers?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

i liked this framework but i have a question, what about controllers when using a custom transport for mictroservices?  i mean, i can use normal TCP transport for controllers in my modules and also use the custom transport defined by me?

I want to use a custom transport server in my microservices but i feel like the frameworks is loosed or i don't know how to use controllers in this setup; for explain it better i want my microservices to communicate using sometime like websockets but also i want to access the microservices using controllers TCP so the best form is to create two apps in the main.ts? one with my custom transport (without controllers) and the other using tcp transport (with controllers, services etc)?

And also which is the purpose of loading a module in a microservice using custom transport if there will not be controllers that can use the transport?

The documentation is not clear about this.